# Processor affinity via powershell

Tags: powershell, affinity

The following powershell script is expected to set processor affinity for a user.

```
Param( [string] $Username )
[int] $affinity = 63
get-process -IncludeUserName | ?{$_.UserName -eq $Username} | %{
    $_.ProcessorAffinity = $affinty
}
```

It has to use 6 cores (from 0 to 5). However, by running `. .\Set-MyAffinity.ps1 -username "test"`, I see no change in the running processes.

Comment: Have you verified that the `UserName` property value of the target process(es) is actually `test` and not `COMPUTERNAME\test` or similar?

Comment: OK that is right. It is now working. How can I reset that? I mean using all cores.

Comment: How many cores do you have? You can calculate "all cores set" with `[math]::Pow(2,(Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).NumberOfLogicalProcessors) - 1`  (assuming you have only one CPU installed)

Comment: Actually there are two CPUs on motherboard. Should I use `2*((Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).NumberOfLogicalProcessors) - 1)`?

Comment: Yes, or more generalized: `[math]::Pow(2,$(Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor |Measure-Object NumberOfLogicalProcessors -Sum).Sum) - 1`